# Nginx hosting mutliple webpages of multiple domain names?

Tags: nginx, dns, ip, nginx-config

I have 4 webpages all hosted in nginx on ports 8521, 8522, 8523, 8524. I used to access them using using my Ip:port (eg. 192.168.82.1:8521 only example not actual ip). Now I registered 4 domain names, www.domain1.com, www.domain2.com, www.domain3.com, www.domain4.com. But the domain resolution is somehow www.domain1.com:8521.

How can I change this to www.domain1.com to get the page instead of www.domain1.com:8521

Comment: Use the default port: 80 for `http` and 443 for `https`.

Comment: The things is I have to host all 4 webpages in the same server in nginx under different domain names.

Comment: See the `server_name` directive. Read [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.

Comment: Yes, but the domain name is appended with the port number in the url for all the 4 different domains.

Comment: Please share your nginx-configs and I will gladly try helping you.